# SQL delete and dependency

Tags: sql-server

Anyone know of a tool or script to delete data from a table and have it also deleted foreign key related rows?

This database is massive with lots of relationships. We are looking for an automated approach.

Cascade delete is not enabled.  Many tables have multiple foreign key constraints.

Thanks!

p.s. I have seen many SO posts that all suggest enabling cascade delete or how to do this with very simple one or two table related entities. We have a very complex large table with many relationships.

**Tried these and they did not work as expected.** We still saw referential constraint errors.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2958.script-to-create-all-foreign-keys.aspx
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/12/02/sql-server-how-to-disable-and-enable-all-constraint-for-table-and-database/

Comment: There is no shortcut here. You have to delete the children first. And finding those relationships is incredibly difficult to do with a tool...unless that tool is a human. All puns aside, this really can't be automated.

Comment: Sometimes, the reason cascades cannot be applied is because the cascading deletes cause "cycles", and it's these cycles which make it all but impossible to manage with any kind of automated approach.

Comment: The doomsayers notwithstanding, *of course* this can be automated. Finding all related records through the foreign key constraints is a straightforward graph traversal. The only reason this can't be done by making every constraint `CASCADE` is because SQL Server is very conservative when it comes to enabling constraints that could *possibly* cause cycles (regardless of whether they actually occur). That said, just because it *can* be automated doesn't make it easy, because T-SQL is a terrible programming language. Writing a robust tool for this unfortunately exceeds the bounds of a SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the same solution. I think this might work for you. 
check out the [**Deleting Specific SQL Server Records with Foreign Keys**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4059/script-to-delete-data-from-sql-server-tables-with-foreign-key-constraints/) portion on this page there you will get a script which can be use to print all the delete query which you need to fire to remove all the depended record from your database. And to execute that query's replace print with exec and your all depend rows will be removed from your complex database :)